# Can't fetch data from local IP in release build

Tags: fetch, react-native

My app scan local network using fetch() to localize device.

All works very well in debug (emulator or physical device with usb debugging), but after building release, my all requests fails. I don't even know how to debug it.

If I hard-code IP and send any request to my device (http://192.168.0.XX/api) - it also fails

Tried adding permissions to manifest, but didnt help.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
```

Any ideas?

//edit: code https://pastebin.com/eFgVsi3Z

//edit2: Alert.alert + JSON.stringify() in catch gave me this:

`{"line": 138,"column":2655,"sourceURL":"index.android.bundle"}`

//edit3: solution: add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to `<application>` in AndroidManifest.json to be able to "talk" with local devices in release builds

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: @MalikHezretov here is example of simplest query working on debug release and doesnt working on final release build: https://pastebin.com/eFgVsi3Z

debug: I see console log and alert 200
release: Nothing happens

Comment: What is the device model ?

Comment: I had similar issue, fetch was not working on release build but it was working on debug mode. That issue happened to me for only Android devices which has API less than 21 and it worked well above API 22. The issue was TLS version of old android devices which doesn't enabled TLS 1.2 by default.

Comment: Thank you for your replies @MalikHezretov, I have added solution in edit